# apolloClient.subsribe is undefined

Tags: apollo, graphql-subscriptions

I am trying to subscribe the apollo and I am getting following error

`apolloClient.Subsribe is undefined`

Attaching my client side subscription

```
const networkInterface = createNetworkInterface('http://localhost:8000/graphql');

const wsClient = new SubscriptionClient(`ws://localhost:8000/`, {
                 reconnect: true,
                 connectionParams: {
                 }
}); 

const networkInterfaceWithSubscriptions = addGraphQLSubscriptions(networkInterface,wsClient);


const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
    networkInterface: networkInterfaceWithSubscriptions
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because of the wrong name .

`apolloClient.subscribe` fixes my issue